# Changing the From field for an email activity in a plug-in

Tags: plugins, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

When an email is sent to a queue and there is a contact associated with the "From" email in CRM, upon promoting an email to an email activity the system automatically fills in the "From" field with the contact information. However, if a user with the same email exists in CRM, too, then the system always picks up the system user instead of the contact. I need to override this behaviour to ALWAYS pick up the contact if one with the email exists.

I created a post-operation plug-in (tried a pre-operation plug-in, too) for the event Create for email, trying to override the From field. The problem is, it does not work. When I debug the plug-in, it goes quietly past the assignment without any errors and then the same plug-in fires for the same email again. And again. And again.

When I try instead to create a new email and use the same ActivityList[] I was trying to use for the entity that triggered the event, it works. It seems that the problem is that CRM does not allow changing the From field from a plug-in, or am I doing something wrong? If it's a limitation enforced by CRM, is there a way around it?

My code is below:

```
var email = ((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]).ToEntity<Email>();
```

...

```
var oldFrom = ((EntityCollection)email.Attributes["from"]).Entities;
List<ActivityParty> newFrom = new List<ActivityParty>(); 
foreach (Entity party in oldFrom)
{
   EntityReference entRef = (EntityReference)party.Attributes["partyid"];
   if (entRef.LogicalName == SystemUser.EntityLogicalName)
      user = userLogic.Get(new Guid(entRef.Id.ToString()));
   if (user == null) return;
   string emailAddress = user.InternalEMailAddress;
   Contact contact = contactLogic.LookupPASIndividual("", emailAddress);
   if (contact != null)
   { newFrom.Add(new ActivityParty() {PartyId = new EntityReference(Contact.EntityLogicalName, contact.ContactId.Value) });
   }
   else
      return;
}
email.From = newFrom;
```

**Update:** So I registered the plug-in on Pre-validation now and it's not triggered when an email activity is created by a router, it IS triggered when a user creates an email in CRM though...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't changing the email which is processed at all.

```
var email = ((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]).ToEntity<Email>();
```

This line converts the record which is currently processed to an object of type `email`. You modify the record which is not in scope of the operation. You have to modify the `From` of the target (either directly or write it back).

For the processing stages: take a look at the [Event Execution Pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327941.aspx). Pre-Validation is to early for your task. I'am not quite sure when the address resolution is done, but I would try to do your conversion Pre-Create.

Comment: Thanks but I doubt that's the issue because I have no problems setting the Regarding field on Pre-Create using the email variable whereas if I try to set the From field, there is an error. I also tried to write back to the inputparameters (context.InputParameters["Target"] = email;) but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a workaround: created an async Post-Event that associates the email activity with the contact if a contact with the same email exists, leaving the user associated with the email in the "From" field.